# Sequential testing of hypothesis

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation, sequential-analysis

Let $\{X_n : n ≥ 1\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with common density $f_\theta(\cdot )$. Lets  we want to test
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{cc}
H_0: & \theta=\theta_0 \\
H_1: & \theta= \theta_1
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}

where $\theta_0\neq \theta_1$,Using  a sequential test.

"Sequential hypothesis testing is statistical analysis where the sample size is not fixed in advance. Instead data are evaluated as they are collected, and further sampling is stopped in accordance with a pre-defined stopping rule as soon as significant results are observed".

Consider

$$Z_n=\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}=\frac{f_{H_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}{f_{H_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)},$$

I want to show if $H_1$  is true
$$Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} 0$$  and if $H_0$ is true
$$Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} +\infty.$$

To see this, following R code may help.

```
 R code:
```

```r
 n<-35
 theta0<-0
 theta1<-.5
 set.seed(1)
 x<-rnorm(n,theta0,1)
 Zn<-c()
 for(i in 1:n){
 Zn[i]<-prod(dnorm(x[1:i],theta0,1))/prod(dnorm(x[1:i],theta1,1))
 }
 par(mfrow=c(1,2),,main="H_0 is true")
 plot(1:n,Zn,type="l")
 set.seed(2)
 x<-rnorm(n,theta1,1)
 Zn<-c()
 for(i in 1:n){
 Zn[i]<-prod(dnorm(x[1:i],theta0,1))/prod(dnorm(x[1:i],theta1,1))
 }
 plot(1:n,Zn,type="l",main="H_1 is true")
 ##output
```

[image]

So the questions are: Is the following calculation is right and what is the meaning of these results.

First I want to show

$$\ Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} 0 \ \ \ under \ H_1 $$

The proof has two parts,

a) $Z_n$ is a positive  martingale so it converge almost surely if $H_1$ is true

b) $Z_n\longrightarrow 0$ if $H_1$ is true

**part a)**

1. Checking the condition $E_{H_1}|Z_n|<+\infty$

$Z_n\geq 0$

$$E_{H_1}|Z_n|=E(Z_n)=\int \cdots \int \frac{f_{\theta_0}(x_1,\cdots, x_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(x_1,\cdots, x_n)} f_{\theta_1}(x_1,\cdots, x_n) dx_1\, \cdots \, dx_n$$

$$\int \cdots \int f_{\theta_0}(x_1,\cdots, x_n) dx_1\, \cdots \, dx_n=1<+\infty$$

2. Checking the condition
   $E(Z_{(n+1)}|X_1,\cdots , X_n)=Z_n$

$$E(Z_{(n+1)}|X_1,\cdots , X_n)=
E_{H_1}\left(\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_{n+1})}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_{n+1})} |X_1,\cdots , X_n\right)
$$
$$=\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}  E_{H_1}\left(\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_{n+1})}{f_{\theta_1}(X_{n+1})} \right)=\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}=Z_n$$

$Z_n$ is a positive martingale so it converges almost surely.

**part b)** $Z_n\longrightarrow 0$ if $H_1$ is true.

Since $Z_n\geq 0$, If I show $E(\sqrt{Z_n})=0$ so $Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} 0$

$$E_{H_1}(\sqrt{Z_n})=E_{H_1}(\sqrt{\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1,\cdots, X_n)}})
=\prod_{i=1}^{n} E_{H_1}(\sqrt{\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_i)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_i)}}) =\left(E_{H_1}(\sqrt{\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1)}})\right)^n $$
By Jensen's inequality

$$a=E_{H_1}(\sqrt{\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1)}})< \sqrt{E_{H_1}(\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_i)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_i)}}) =1$$

so

$$E_{H_1}(\sqrt{Z_n})=\left(E\sqrt{\frac{f_{\theta_0}(X_1)}{f_{\theta_1}(X_1)}})\right)^n=(a)^n$$ where $a< 1$($a=1$ not happen since the condition of equality in Jensen inequality not happen in this case)

so $n\longrightarrow +\infty$

$$E_{H_1}(\sqrt{Z_n})\longrightarrow 0$$
Since

$$E_{H_1}(\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty}Z_{n}})
=E_{H_1}(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{Z_{n}})=E_{H_1}(\liminf_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{Z_{n}})
\overset{Fatou's \ lemma }{\leq} \liminf_{n \to \infty} E_{H_1}( \sqrt{Z_{n}})=0
$$

So if $H_1$ is true,
$$Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} 0$$

For second case,that is,$H_0$ is true,
$$Z_n\overset{Almost \ surely }{\longrightarrow} +\infty.$$ I do not know how to show $Z_n\longrightarrow +\infty$.

I hope if I ignored any condition, assumption , ... you mention it.
Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide or any clarification.